# Xaml Binding To Custom Class in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Lets say I have a really basic class with a few properties. Eg:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Something = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
            OrOther = "Proin dignissim, nunc non tincidunt imperdiet, magna urna malesuada enim";
        }
        public string Something { get; set; }
        public string OrOther { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to databind to this in Xaml, how would I do this?
I've tried binding directly to the object, so in my Xaml page code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyClass anInstance;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            anInstance = new MyClass();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
```

And then in my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">

    <Label Text="{Binding anInstance.Something}" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

And I've also tried setting the BindingContext on a parent control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout BindingContext="anInstance">        
        <Label Text="{Binding Something}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

But it just doesn't work. I've also tried setting the bindingcontext of the page to anInstance:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyClass anInstance;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            anInstance = new MyClass();
            BindingContext = anInstance;
        }
    }
```

And Just binding to its properties on the xaml side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">

        <Label Text="{Binding Something}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

But again, all I get are blank pages.
It seems that at least one of these should work.
Whats the recommended way to bind to properties on a custom class like this?

**edit**

Taking on board @jason comments, I've also tried this:

```
public MyClass anInstance
        {
            get
            {
                return _anInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                _anInstance = value;
            }
        }
        private MyClass _anInstance { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            anInstance = new MyClass();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
```

And the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout BindingContext="anInstance">
        <Label Text="{Binding Something}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding OrOther}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

But again a blank page...

Same result with:

```
private MyClass anInstance { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            anInstance = new MyClass();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout BindingContext="anInstance">
        <Label Text="{Binding Something}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding OrOther}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: your first example doesn't work because "anInstance" is not a property.  Your final example should work.

Comment: Neither code shown will works. Your anInstance object must be a property. It means that it must be declared like `public MyClass anInstance { get; set; }`.

Comment: in both of your appended examples, you are setting the BindingContext in both the XAML and code behind.  Pick on or the other, not both.  It's confusing at best.  I generally find it clearer to set it in the code behind.

Comment: also, just noticed that your anInstance property is private - I believe it needs to be either public or protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Your property needs to be public (or protected might work. Then you're setting the binding context to `this`. Which is fine. For the record, I am using this code:

```
public MyClass AnInstance { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AnInstance = new MyClass();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

Now in your XAML, you can access it's properties like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingTest"
             x:Class="DataBindingTest.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding AnInstance.Something}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="{Binding AnInstance.OrOther}" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If you do not want the property name `AnInstance` prefix, set the binding context directly to the instance of the `MyClass` object, like this:

```
public MyClass AnInstance { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AnInstance = new MyClass();
    BindingContext = AnInstance;
}
```

You can now use the properties belonging to the `MyClass` directly, like so: `<Label Text="{Binding OrOther}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />`

Comment: Thanks. Really useful. Why though, can't i set the context to this in the codebehind, then on a stacklayout set the BindingContext to AnInstance. Inside of that then just use the fields on AnInstance without needing the FQ name?

Comment: Also, is it documented anywhere about binding only working with public fields? Why does it need to be public if they are both partials of the same class? Just curious thats all...